# attempt to index global 'volMusicTickOn' (a nil value). Listener Errors

Tags: lua, null, initialization, listener, coronasdk

I was trying to make a simple videogame for smartphones, well, what i'm now trying to do is that when i click on the 'volMusicTickOn' object, this must disappear and the music stops. I've done this with a function listener but i got an error on calling the listener, here's the code:

```
local settings = composer.newScene()

local particlesTable = {}

local particlesGroup = display.newGroup()


local options =
{
  width = 600,
  height = 600,
  numFrames = 2,
  sheetContentWidth = 1200,
  heetContentHeight = 600

}

local tickSheet = graphics.newImageSheet( "rectTick_sheet.png",  options )


--


--

function settings:create( event )

-- Dichiarazione oggeti e codice eseguibile
    num=0

    local sceneGroup = self.view

    background = display.newImageRect( sceneGroup, "background.png",  1280 , 720 )
    background.x = display.contentCenterX
    background.y = display.contentCenterY

    volMusicTickOn = display.newImageRect(  "rectTick_on.png",  100, 100 )
    volMusicTickOn.name = "volMusicTickOn"
    volMusicTickOn.x = display.contentCenterX - 250
    volMusicTickOn.y = display.contentCenterY - 100


end

function settings:show( event )
  local sceneGroup = self.view
    local phase = event.phase

    if ( phase == "will" ) then
        -- Code here runs when the scene is still off screen (but is about to come on screen)

    elseif ( phase == "did" ) then

        if event.phase=="began"then

        end
        if event.phase=="ended"then

        end

    end
end

function settings:hide( event )
  local sceneGroup = self.view
    local phase = event.phase

    if ( phase == "will" ) then
        -- Code here runs when the scene is still off screen (but is about to come on screen)

    elseif ( phase == "did" ) then
        -- Code here runs when the scene is entirely on screen

    end
end

function settings:destroy( event )
    local sceneGroup = self.view
end

-- Funzioni

  local function remove(particle)
      display.remove( particle )
      table.remove( particlesTable, num)
    end

    local function removeParticle( particle )
      timer.performWithDelay(1000, transition.to( particle, {alpha=0, time=350, onComplete=remove(particle) } ))
    end

    local function removetotally( particle )
      display.remove( particle )
      table.remove( particlesTable, num )
    end

    function dimParticle( particle )
        transition.to( particle, {alpha=0, time=500, onComplete = removetotally, onCompleteParams = particle})
    end

    local function generateParticles()
      local xy=math.random(30,70)
      local newParticle = display.newImageRect( particlesGroup,  objectSheet , chooseColor(math.random(3)), xy, xy )
      table.insert( particlesTable, newParticle )
      num = num+1
      newParticle.x = (math.random(1280)*math.random(88932))%1280
      newParticle.y = (math.random(720)*math.random(13546))%720
      newParticle.alpha = 0
      transition.to( newParticle, {alpha=1, time=150, onComplete=dimParticle, onCompleteParams=newParticle})
    end

    local function generateParticlesSmall()
      local xy=math.random(5,15)
      local newParticle = display.newImageRect( particlesGroup,  objectSheet , 1, xy, xy )
      table.insert( particlesTable, newParticle )
      num = num+1
      newParticle.x = (math.random(1280)*math.random(88932))%1280
      newParticle.y = (math.random(720)*math.random(13546))%720
      newParticle.alpha = 0
      transition.to( newParticle, {alpha=1, time=150, onComplete=dimParticle, onCompleteParams=newParticle})
    end

    local function chooseColor(n)
      if n==1 then
        return 8
      elseif n==2 then
        return 9
      elseif n==3 then
        return 10
      end
    end

    function changeMusicVolumeStatus(event)
      if audio.isChannelPaused( 1 ) then
        audio.resume( 1 )
      else
        audio.pause( 1 )
      end
      return true
    end

    local function changeEffectsVolumeStatus(event)
      if audio.isChannelPaused( 2 ) then
        audio.resume( 2 )
      else
        audio.pause( 2 )
      end
      return true
    end

-- Chiamate e Listener Del Runtime

bigPTimer1=timer.performWithDelay( 1, generateParticles, 0 )
bigPTimer2=timer.performWithDelay( 1, generateParticles, 0 )
smallPTimer=timer.performWithDelay( 1, generateParticlesSmall, 0 )

settings:addEventListener( "create", settings )
settings:addEventListener( "show", settings )
settings:addEventListener( "hide", settings )
settings:addEventListener( "destroy", settings )
volMusicTickOn:addEventListener( "tap", changeMusicVolumeStatus )
volMusicTickOff:addEventListener( "tap", changeMusicVolumeStatus )

--

return settings
```

Here is the error i got

```
16:49:45.126  ERROR: Runtime error
16:49:45.126  C:\Users\lpasi\Downloads\Progetto 1-20170725T134427Z-001\Progetto 1\settings.lua:167: attempt to index global 'volMusicTickOn' (a nil value)
16:49:45.126  stack traceback:
16:49:45.126    [C]: in function 'error'
16:49:45.126    ?: in function 'gotoScene'
16:49:45.126    C:\Users\lpasi\Downloads\Progetto 1-20170725T134427Z-001\Progetto 1\menu.lua:36: in function '_onRelease'
16:49:45.126    ?: in function '?'
16:49:45.126    ?: in function <?:654>
16:49:45.126    ?: in function <?:169>
```

I've tried to use also table listeners but nothing changed, pleas lemme know if you solve my problems, Thank You.

Comment: It seems volMusicTickOn is nil, check your path to "rectTick_on.png", is it correct, is file name correct too?

Comment: @Abadziluk  yup, that's not the problem, tried to comment listener and it appears normally on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `settings:create` is called before you try to reference `volMusicTickOn`? Because `settings:create` defines `volMusicTickOn` and thus it will be `nil` until it is called.

As I see it, the `create` event may not be fired until after you reference `volMusicTickOn` for the first time. Your code, because it is event based, is not guaranteed to run what this line sets up:

```
settings:addEventListener( "create", settings )
```

Before this line:

```
volMusicTickOn:addEventListener( "tap", changeMusicVolumeStatus )
volMusicTickOff:addEventListener( "tap", changeMusicVolumeStatus )
```

And this, `volMusicTickOn` might be `nil`

The solution would be to actually move those lines into `settings:create` so you know that `volMusicTickOn` is not `nil` for sure!